# Overwrite image in PIL instead of opening new window

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm sending a stream of JPEG images from a Raspberry Pi to my MBP via a simple socket programme in Python 2.7.

When I read the image from the stream on my MBP, it opens up in Preview and opens a new Preview window for every separate image. I have an fps of about 2/3 and obviously 2/3 new windows per second is impossible to work with.

How can I go about only opening one Preview window and simply overwriting the displayed image? Would OpenCV be the best way to go? If so I am unsure how to.

Here is how I read the stream and display the images:

```
image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
    if not image_len:
        break
    image_stream = io.BytesIO()
    image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))
    image_stream.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(image_stream)
    image.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X Preview seems to automatically reload open images at intervals (always when the window receives focus), but `Image.show` saves a new temporary file each time you use it. I suggest saving each new frame to the same file and then using `subprocess.call` with the OS X `open` command.

This being said, [the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) notes that Image.show is primarily for debugging purposes. For a video with more than a few FPS, you probably want something else. One solution would be an HTML interface with WebSockets, perhaps using something like [AutoBahn](http://autobahn.ws/).